# H2 database connecting to in memory instead of file database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I am stuck in this, trying to change my h2 db from in memory to file based. But everytime on restart, it automatically connects to in memory.

Here is my application.properties

```
server.port=8010
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/transactionsdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
#spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Please help me to progress. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my *application.yml* file and on restart H2 database is connecting to the file database. I have created **test1.mv.db** file in /Users/rohit/ directory.

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:/Users/rohit/test1
    username: sa
    password:
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        bootstrap-mode: default
```

In application start-up logs also I can see the same information

[image]

Comment: HI @Rohit, this test1.mv.db file is created by you or is it automatically created?

Comment: It is automatically created.

Comment: @ManojMajumdar - If my answer helps request you to please accept it so that it helps others as well.

Comment: The problem was with my datasource configuration, I had another embedded datasource configuration in my @configuration file, which ignored the configuration of my properties file